# Does the ZyXEL NAS542 support BitTorrent?

Tags: nas, bittorrent

I've had no luck on Google at all, does anyone know if the NAS542 supports BitTorrent? Or if any similar ZyXEL NAS does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zyxel knowledge base has a page called "How to use Transmission package of NAS series?" [Zyxel Knowledge Base](https://kb.zyxel.com/KB/searchArticle!gwsViewDetail.action?articleOid=014701&lang=EN) the example given is the NAS325, also Deluge seems to be available (both Transmission and Deluge are Bit Torrent clients).

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer for now.